How to Handle Zoom API Rate Limit for Meeting Creation in a Multi-User SaaS Application?
I'm building a SaaS application where multiple users can create Zoom meetings. Currently, I'm using Zoom Server-to-Server OAuth to create meetings via the below endpoint
POST /users/{userId}/meetings
Now according to the Zoom API docs, there is a rate limit of 100 requests per day for meeting creation, and this limit is applied to the userId of the meeting host.
All of my app users are creating meetings through a single Zoom account (for example, appowner@gmail.com) i did this because i am also recording the meetings and then using the transcripts so if i use account of my salesreps that will be difficult for them to setup the tokens, zoom app etc (is this is the only possible way). This works fine for a small number of users, but now that I have 100+ users, each wanting to schedule multiple meetings daily, I am running into the 100 requests/day limit.
